# Confused with Likes Counter using Firebase in Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, posts, social-likes

I am beginner and I am working on an android Project where users like the post that admin posts for them. The likes are updated to firebase when user clicks on the like button. The Issue is even though the user likes or unlikes the post, the likes count is increasing. Please look into it.

**Note:**

```
Log.d(TAG, "Liked onDataChange: "+isLiked);
```

returns false no matter if we like or unlike the shinebutton. Shinebutton is a library.

Link to its GitHub :
[Shinebutton Github](https://github.com/ChadCSong/ShineButton)

**onLike Method:**

```
        @Override
        public void onLike(View v, int position) {

            UploadImage selectedItem = mUploads.get(position);
            String selectedKey = selectedItem.getKey();
            final ShineButton shineButton = new ShineButton(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()));
            shineButton.setBtnFillColor(RED);
            shineButton.setShapeResource(R.raw.heart);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100,100);
            shineButton.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);



            final DatabaseReference likesRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("ImageUploads").child(selectedKey).child("likes");
            likesRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener(){
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NotNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    long numLikes = 0;
                    if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                        numLikes = dataSnapshot.getValue(Long.class);
                    }
                    boolean isLiked = shineButton.isSelected();

                    Log.d(TAG, "Liked onDataChange: "+isLiked);
                    if(isLiked){
                        //If already liked then user wants to unlike the post

                        likesRef.setValue(numLikes-1);

                    }else {
                        //If not liked already then user wants to like the post
                        likesRef.setValue(numLikes+1);
                        shineButton.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

            ShineButton like  =  layout.findViewById(R.id.like_feed);
            System.out.println(RED);
            like.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.like_feed_bg));

        }
```

After the modification of the Code: Now eventhough we like or unlike the count is not increasing or decreasing.

**Onlike Method:**

```
            public void onLike(View v, int position) {

            UploadImage selectedItem = mUploads.get(position);
            String selectedKey = selectedItem.getKey();
            final ShineButton shineButton = new ShineButton(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()));
            shineButton.setBtnFillColor(RED);
            shineButton.setShapeResource(R.raw.heart);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100,100);
            shineButton.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

            final DatabaseReference likesRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("ImageUploads").child(selectedKey).child("likes");
            likesRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener(){
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NotNull final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    long numLikes = 0;

                    if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                        numLikes = dataSnapshot.getValue(Long.class);
                    }

                    final long finalNumLikes = numLikes;

                    shineButton.setOnCheckStateChangeListener(new ShineButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(View view, boolean checked) {


                            if (checked){
                                likesRef.setValue(finalNumLikes-1);
                            }
                            else{
                                likesRef.setValue(finalNumLikes+1);
                            }
                        }
                    });

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

            ShineButton like  =  layout.findViewById(R.id.like_feed);
            System.out.println(RED);
            like.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.like_feed_bg));

        }
```

Comment: Please help me.

Comment: Does `Log.d(TAG, "Liked onDataChange: "+isLiked);` return false when you like it?

Comment: Yes.. It returns false when we unlike it.

Comment: if it returns false then you will keep adding a new like. Try changing it to `if(!isLiked)`

Comment: When we unlike or like it 
boolean isLiked = shinebutton.isSelected(); returns always false.
What to do?

Comment: boolean isLiked = shineButton.isSelected(); is returning false no matter we like or unlike it. What to do?

Comment: Exactly what I thought. You will have to share how you implemented `ShineButton`, I'm not sure what `ShineButton` is, is it a library?

Comment: Shinebutton is a library which seems like a twiiter like button.
Link to GitHub:
https://github.com/ChadCSong/ShineButton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you do not check the state of the button being pressed. You can achieve this by doing the following:

Replace:

```java
if(isLiked){ 
    //If already liked then user wants to unlike the post 
    likesRef.setValue(numLikes-1); }
else { 
    //If not liked already then user wants to like the post 
    likesRef.setValue(numLikes+1);
    shineButton.setEnabled(false); 
}
```

With this:

```java
shineButton.setOnCheckStateChangeListener(new ShineButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() { 
@Override 
    public void onCheckedChanged(View view, boolean checked) { 
        if (checked){
            likesRef.setValue(numLikes+1);
        } else {
            likesRef.setValue(numLikes-1);
        }
    } 
});
```

You will also have to keep reference of the botton for when you close the application. You can do this using `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: The answer is fine but the problem is it says variable numLikes is accessed in innerclass. So I declared globally. Now even though if we like or unlike the number is no changing

Comment: @UdayKiran just make `numLikes` final

Comment: I made it final. Then also it is not increasing or decreasing @HB

Comment: @UdayKiran you said you made it global, please edit you question and show how it lools like now.

Comment: I made it global and tried.. It didn't work .

Then I made it final.. it didn't work.

I will edit and post the question. @HB